# After rebooting with a Hard disk drive with ubuntu 18.04 ISO inside and clicking "Install Ubuntu", I got a black screen. My laptop is Lenovo

Tags: boot

I'm trying to install ubuntu 18.04 on windows 10 Lenovo by rebooting with a usb hard disk drive. I got to the boot menu here:

[Boot Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Me4W.png)

Then, I selected "Install Ubuntu" and clicked "e". Then I replaced "quiet splash" with "nomodeset" ( shown in this picture)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdXeE.png)

Then I got a blank screen.

Any advice on this? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)  FYI, the second image you posted is completely illegible.

Comment: @Nmath: There are 32 answers on that page. Which answer would you suggest the OP start with? He has already tried using `nomodeset`

Answer (score 0):

### Installing to External Drive from External Drive

You first need to install Ubuntu Live to an external drive before you can use it to install Ubuntu. (It is likely much easier to use a Live USB to install Ubuntu to the external drive).

Both **Rufus** and **Etcher** will install Ubuntu Live to an External USB pendrive. Ubuntu Live can then be used to install Ubuntu to the same external drive.

In Rufus select "List USB Hard Drives"

In Etcher select the gear in the upper right hand corner, then select "Unsafe mode"

**Warning**: This will overwrite all data on the external drive.

Remember to unselect these options when done.

Disable internal drive before proceeding.

Once Ubuntu Live is installed to the external drive, boot it in the same BIOS/UEFI mode Windows uses, using the `toram` option.

Press `shift` as soon as the boot starts. Press `esc` then press `F6`, press `esc` again, then type a space and then type `toram`.

Once booted open Nautilus and enter `sudo umount -lrf /dev/sdxy` Where sdxy is the partition containing the running Live Ubuntu.

- Start Install Ubuntu.
- Select Language, click "Continue".
- Select Keyboard layout, click "Continue".
- Select Wireless network, click "Continue". (optional).
- Select installation preference and select "Download updates while installing Ubuntu", (optional), and Select "Install third-party software ...", click "Continue". (Optional).
- If asked about mounted partitions, select Yes, click "Continue".
- Do not use Advanced feature disk encryption for this install method.
- At "Installation type" select "Something else". (Full disk encryption is not working with flash drives).
- Select "Continue".
- Confirm target device for bootloader is correct.
- Select "New Partition Table".
- Click Continue on the drop down.
- Click "free space" and then "+".
- Select "Primary", "Size ..." = 4500 to 6000 MB, "Beginning of this space", Ext4, and Mount point = "/" then OK.
- Click Install now.
- Confirm partitions to be formatted if asked, click continue.
- Select your location. click "Continue".
- Insert your name, computer name, username, password and select
  if you want to log in automatically or require a password. - Click "Continue".
- Wait until install is complete.